# Out-of-order returns from Java Futures

Tags: java, concurrency, future

The only model that I can come up with for running multiple similar processes (SIMD) using 
Java Futures (`java.util.concurrent.Future<T>`) is as follows:

```
class Job extends Callable<T> {
  public T call() {
    // ...
  }
}
List<Job> jobs = // ...
List<Future<T>> futures = ExecutorService.invokeAll(jobs);
for (Future<T> future : futures) {
  T t = future.get();
  // Do something with t ...
}
```

The problem with this model is that if job 0 takes a long time to complete, but jobs 1, 2, and 3 have already completed, the `for` loop will wait to get the return value from job 0.

Is there any model that allows me to get each `Future` result as it becomes available without just calling `Future.isDone()` and busy waiting (or calling `Thread.sleep()`) if none are ready yet?

Comment: I'd say the answer, as you have hinted at, is to use the isDone() method as a guard for the get() method.  Sounds like the ExecutorService itself would benefit from being able to give you the completed jobs, but I don't think that's an option.  Can you not do something in the Job which calls back when it completes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try out the `ExecutorCompletionService`:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

You would simply submit your tasks and call take until you've received all Futures.

Comment: I was not aware of `ExecutorCompletionService`. I'll have to take a look at this.

Answer (score 14):

Consider using [`ListenableFuture`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com). They let you basically add a continuation to execute when the future has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add what you want done to the job?

```
class Job extends Runnable {
  public void run() {
    // ...
    T result = ....
    // do something with the result.
  }
}
```

That way it will process the result as soon as it is available, concurrently. ;)

Comment: That won't work if the receiver is a Swing GUI. I suppose you could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, but suppose you want to update a progress bar -- gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A [`CompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) can be polled for available results.

If all you want is the results as they become available however, we wrote an [`AsyncCompleter`](https://labs.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CONCURRENT/AsyncCompleter) that abstracts away the detail of completion service usage. It lets you submit an `Iterable<Callable<T>>` of jobs and returns an `Iterable<T>` of results that blocks on `next()` and returns the results in completion order.

Comment: See the answer by Thomas Jungblut above. The `ExecutorCompletionService` may do the same thing as your `AsyncCompleter`.

Comment: AsyncCompleter wraps an ExecutorCompletionService under the covers and handles all the . The interface is simply: `AsyncCompleter.invokeAll(Iterable<Callable<T> jobs)` which returns an Iterable<T> of results which blocks on calls to next(). It doesn't declare InterruptedExceptions, you don't poll(). In short, it is much simpler to use than the `CompletionService`.